# VBOX with Ubuntu on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I want to install Ubuntu on Windows 7 64bit with VBOX.
Should I install 64bit or 32 bit Ubuntu on the VBOX - does it really matter on a virtual machine?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124/can-i-run-a-64-bit-vmware-image-on-a-32-bit-machine

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. When you create a new machine in VBOX it will asks you which architecture you would like the machine to have (in the first menu when you chose preconfigured settings for OSes).

Actually even in a real 64-bits machine a 32-bits will work. However it is not optimised for the architecture.